# Why Notification always display last Notification whenever touch on anyone of notification in android

Tags: android, push-notification

I tried to create notification in android apps. After I create one transaction, I call "ShowNotification" method to display notification in the device.

```
public void showNotification(String screen, String message) {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("screen", screen);
    intent.putExtra("message",message);
    int id = 1;
    try {
        // get latest id from SQLite DB
        id = DbManager.getInstance().getIntDbKeyValue("notif_id");
        if (id < 1) {
            id = 1;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    intent.putExtra("notif_id", id + "");

    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    Notification n = new Notification.Builder(this).setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name)).setContentText(message)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setContentIntent(pIntent).setAutoCancel(true)
            .setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
            .build();
    // set next running id into SQLite DB
    DbManager.getInstance().setDbKeyValue("notif_id", (id + 1) + "");
    notificationManager.notify(id, n);
}
```

I can able to see correct message on the notification list of device.
When I touch on the notification, I would like to display the message with alert on the screen.

The problem is that it always display last notification in alert box whenever I touch the notification. Below is the code that I wrote in MainActivity Class.

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    try {
        checkIntent(intent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void checkIntent(Intent intent) {
        try {
            int id = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("notif_id"));
            if (id > 0 ) {
                String s = intent.getStringExtra("screen");
                if ("XXXXXX".equalsIgnoreCase(s)) {
                    Fragment f = new MonitoringFragment();
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("message", intent.getStringExtra("message"));
                    f.setArguments(bundle);
                    showFragment(f, false);
                }else{
                    showFragment(new XxxxFragment(), false);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
}
```

Could anyone of you please suggest me that why it always get last NOtificationID whenver I touch the notification?

I suspect that PendingIntent make overwrite all intent data whenever create new intent.

> PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
>   PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

If there any other way not to keep every notification with its notificationId and message?

Comment: There must be a logical error in saving and retrieving notification key value can you check the notification key with debugger if it is increasing every time or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to add randon requestCode for each intent instead of using 0 for every intent.

> int requestCode = new Random().nextInt();
>   PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, requestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);